# Publish Web Application's UI Extremely Slow

Tags: visual-studio-2012

Web Application Publishing in VS2012 used to be quite fast for me, but for the last week or so the UI exhibits very long pauses:

- When I first right-click the project and select Publish, the publish UI takes about 30 seconds to come up (VS is unreactive during that time).
- If I select a New Package, the associated UI takes up to 60 seconds to appear.

The actual publishing is quite fast.  It's just the VS2012 UI that is unresponsive.

This is similar to [Publish very slow in VS 2012](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/766676/publish-very-slow-in-vs-2012).  However, that ticket is about publishing itself being very slow rather than about the publishing UI.

Given that the UI was fast and has become slow, it it possible that some setting or configuration is causing the slowness?  Any idea how to make it fast again?

Comment: Make sure you have free physical memory. VS2012 runs like a legless dog when virtual memory is involved. I get popups even opening a file... due to only 4GB RAM.

Comment: @leppie: I have 32GB on Win8 64 and an i7 with a fast SSD for the OS and fast RAID 10 for VS and source code.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: I have a simlar setup (16GB/ SSD) and it is still a dog to publish.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem when I had multiple publish profiles in my solution configured to publish to servers that were no longer available or were offline. I was using the File System publish method.

I believe that Visual Studio tries to connect to the servers and the UI hangs until the connections time out.

Removing the profiles that were no longer in use resolved the slowness issue for me. Remove them by selecting Manage Profiles... in the Publish wizard, and then use the Remove button to delete them.